# Multithread PDF manipulation

Tags: java, windows, multithreading, pdf, cmd

I'm writing a java program whose operation is summarized as follows:

- The subfolder with the specified name is selected in the source
  folder.
- All the pdfs are taken and converted into txt files in
  the target folder.
- The name of an item is searched inside the
  txt.
- If the name is found then the pdf from source to target is
  copied.
- All the txt from the target folder are deleted, in this
  way all the pdfs containing the searched word remain.

"It all works", the problem is that the txt files are not deleted from target and I can not understand why. Thanks in advance, best regards.

Launcher.java:

```
import java.lang.String;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;

public class Launcher {

  // campi
  int status = 1;
  static String source = "C:\\Users\\MyUser\\Desktop\\source\\";
  static String target = "C:\\Users\\MyUser\\Desktop\\target\\";

  public static void main(String [] args) {
    // strings
    String src = source;
    String item = "";

    // init
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("\nFornitore: ");
    src += scan.nextLine().toUpperCase() + "\\";
    System.out.print("Item: ");
    item = scan.nextLine();

    // notifier
    Launcher launcher = new Launcher();

    // threads
    MakerThread maker = new MakerThread(launcher, src, target);
    SearcherThread searcher = new SearcherThread(launcher, src, target, item);
    CleanupThread cleaner = new CleanupThread(launcher, target);

    // run
    maker.start();
    searcher.start();
    cleaner.start();
  }
}
```

MakerThread.java:

```
import java.io.File;

public class MakerThread extends Thread {
  // campi
  String src = "";
  String target = "";
  Launcher launcher;

  // costruttore
  public MakerThread(Launcher launcher, String src, String target) {
    this.src = src;
    this.target = target;
    this.launcher = launcher;
  }

  // metodi
  @Override
  public void run() {
      try{
          synchronized (launcher) {
              File folder = new File(this.src);

              for (File f : folder.listFiles()) {
                // spin-lock
                while (launcher.status != 1){
                  launcher.wait();
                }

                if(f.isFile() && f.getName().endsWith("pdf")) {
                  System.out.println("PDF TROVATO: " + f.getName());

                  // input
                  String input = win_str(src + f.getName());

                  // output
                  String output = target;
                  output += f.getName().replaceAll(".pdf", ".txt");
                  output = win_str(output);

                  // command
                  String command = "cmd /C java -jar ./pdfbox-app-2.0.11.jar ExtractText ";
                  command += input + " " + output;
                  Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
                  p1.waitFor();
                }
              }

              // set status, awake other threads
              launcher.status = 2;
              launcher.notifyAll();
          }
      }catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println("Exception: "+e.getMessage());
      }
  }

  private String win_str(String str) {
    return "\"" + str + "\"";
  }
}
```

SearcherThread.java:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class SearcherThread extends Thread {
  // campi
  String src = "";
  String target = "";
  String item = "";
  Launcher launcher;

  // costruttore
  public SearcherThread(Launcher launcher, String src, String target, String item) {
    this.target = target;
    this.src = src;
    this.item = item;
    this.launcher = launcher;
  }

  // metodi
  @Override
  public void run() {
    try{
        synchronized (launcher) {
            File folder = new File(this.target);

            for(File f : folder.listFiles()) {
              // spin-lock
              while (launcher.status != 2){
                launcher.wait();
              }

              if(f.isFile() && f.getName().endsWith("txt")) {
                System.out.println("SEARCHING IN: " + f.getName());

                // init
                String line;
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(target+f.getName())));

                // txt search
                while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                  if(line.contains(item)) {
                    System.out.println("  [" + item + "]" + " trovato in " + f.getName() + "\n");

                    // input
                    String pdf = f.getName().replaceAll(".txt", ".pdf");
                    String input = win_str(src+pdf);

                    // output
                    String output = win_str(target);

                    // command
                    String command = "cmd /C copy " + input + " " + output;
                    Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
                    p1.waitFor();
                    break;
                  }
                }
              }
            }

            // set status, awake other threads
            launcher.status = 3;
            launcher.notifyAll();
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception: "+e.getMessage());
    }
  }

  private String win_str(String str) {
    return "\"" + str + "\"";
  }
}
```

CleanupThread.java:

```
import java.io.File;

public class CleanupThread extends Thread {
  // campi
  String target = "";
  Launcher launcher;

  // costruttore
  public CleanupThread(Launcher launcher, String target) {
    this.target = target;
    this.launcher = launcher;
  }

  // metodi
  @Override
  public void run() {
      try{
          synchronized (launcher) {
              File folder = new File(this.target);

              for (File f : folder.listFiles()) {
                // spin-lock
                while (launcher.status != 3){
                  launcher.wait();
                }

                if(f.isFile() && f.getName().endsWith("txt")) {
                  System.out.println("CLEANING UP: " + f.getName());

                  // input
                  String input = win_str(target + f.getName());

                  // command
                  String command = "cmd /C del " + input;
                  Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
                  p1.waitFor();
                }
              }

              // set status, awake other threads
              launcher.status = 1;
              launcher.notifyAll();
          }
      }catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println("Exception: "+e.getMessage());
      }
  }

  private String win_str(String str) {
    return "\"" + str + "\"";
  }
}
```

Comment: Gyro's rule of thumb: using an external command to do something in a Java program is wrong in at least 8 of 10 cases (Hint: java has a rich File API). And you shouldn't use plain Threads nowadays (this so 1990s)

Comment: Please reduce your code to a [mcve] of the problem. You are posting too much code.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel The program is a pdf management program that uses three threads for accessing, writing and deleting files. Before posting the question I tried to rewrite it several times and I already reduced it... Unfortunately I do not think I can reduce it any more without having to start over again

Comment: As @Gyro implied: why do you use a shell `del` command instead of a java `File` method? And why don't you try to determine whether deleting was successful?